# URL's not copying/deploying to UAT or Prod when I deploy Synapse workspace Dev pipelines using Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse

URL's not copying/Deploy to UAT or Prod when I deploy Synapse workspace Dev pipelines using Azure DevOps.

Link include: Web activity Url's or API links, Or linked services links.

[Synapse Web activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGGqj.png)

Tried re-deploying but not worked out(with parameter values)

Comment: Check the template, can you see the links parameter? You would need to create a custom template-parameters-definition.json file, you can follow this article: [CICD Automation in Synapse Analytics: taking advantage of custom parameters in Workspace Templates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/cicd-automation-in-synapse-analytics-taking-advantage-of-custom/ba-p/3513546).